# Fix firebase issue with realtime databsase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have tried to use database of Firebase in my project but for some reason it does not let me put data in the database

I have searched in Google but I didn't find any responses anywhere that are correct, some said that it was the google-play but my simulator is good in all aspects and updated

```
public void goToHomeActivityButtonClickableFuntion(View view) {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(editTextEmail.getText().toString(), editTextPassword.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("H").child("email").setValue("h");

                        } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If there any error/stack trace, please [edit] your question and post it here.

Comment: Is this line `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` providing any informations? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the firebase console and make the read and write rules true in the section of database. Please follow the [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart) or look at the attached image.[image: enable the firebase database for testing]